# Executing a shell command within PHP

Tags: php, shell, pdf-to-html

On the terminal, I run this successfully within the web application's directory:

```
pdftohtml -c -noframes "documents/document1.pdf"
```

Now I want to do this through PHP, so I wrote a `shell.sh` file that looks like this:

```
sudo pdftohtml -c -noframes "documents/$file"
exit 0
```

Then I wrote this in php:

```
$output = shell_exec("file='document1.pdf' shell.sh");
```

It doesn't work, I expect to see html files generated, but I get some empty html files..since the command worked fine through the terminal, then I think the problem is in the way I execute it from php

echoing $output doesn't show anything.. what do I do wrong?

Comment: `sudo` at the very least needs a password, no?

Comment: Are you running the PHP file through `sudo`, so it gets the permissions you used before?

Comment: It looks like there's a couple helpful hints in the comments of the `shell_exec` [reference page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) specifically what was mentioned about `sudo` needing a password and also the possibility that you might need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` (`2>&1`) to get any output.

Comment: try redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null` and see if you still get output `pdftohtml 2>/dev/null -c -noframes "documents/document1.pdf"`. If you don't see anything then it means that the output is written to `stderr` and you'll need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` for `shell_exec` to give any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need specify path to the script (or `./` if it is the current directory):

```
shell_exec("file='document1.pdf' ./shell.sh")
```

Comment: This gives me a ``shell.sh: command not found``

I should get an html file per page in document1.pdf, I only get a single empty one

Comment: run `file='document1.pdf' ./shell.sh`